# Generating JSON from a xml document / Powershell / controlling the array format

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I need to read some data from an XML document and then format it as JSON to submit as a POST to a new webservice we're deploying.

While I got *most* of it to work, I'm not really happy with how the JSON is coming out (I can modify the webservice if needed, so the data format issue I have now is mostly cosmetic).

So... Data source (the xml file):

```xml
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://somemachine"
                  ConnectionTimeout="10000"
                  CacheEnabled="true"
                  CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                  ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" />
```

Powershell code reading this/generating the JSON:

```ps
$configRepository = @()
foreach($attr in ($xml.Configuration.ConfigRepository).attributes)
{
    $configRepository += @{ $attr.Name = $attr.Value} 
}
```

When output to JSON, I get something like this:

```js
"ConfigRepository":  [
    {
        "CacheEnabled":  "true"
    },
    {
        "CacheExpirationDuration": "600"
    },
    {
        "ConnectionTimeout":  "10000"
    },
    {
        "ServiceMonitorPollDuration":  "10"
    },
    {
        "ServiceUri":  "http://somemachine"
    },
]
```

**The actual question:**

Is there a way to keep my PS code generic, but with an output like this instead?

```js
"ConfigRepository":  [
    {
        "CacheEnabled":  "true"
        "CacheExpirationDuration": "600"
        "ConnectionTimeout":  "10000"
        "ServiceMonitorPollDuration":  "10"
        "ServiceUri":  "http://somemachine"
    },
]
```

Comment: `$configRepository` is an array. How are you converting the array to JSON?

Comment: Using the standard `ConvertTo-Json` - this array is part of a much larger array, I posted only some parts relevant to the question at hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't nest the hashtable in an array - remove `$configRepository = @()`

```
foreach($attr in ($xml.Configuration.ConfigRepository).attributes)
{
    $configRepository += @{ $attr.Name = $attr.Value} 
}
```

Comment: Wow, that simple! Thank you SO much. - I'll accept it when I can (apparently need to wait a few more minutes).

Comment: @NunoLinhares No problem! Reg simplicity, PowerShell is nice like that. [Previously, another StackOverflow soul had the opposite problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433728/powershell-to-form-correctly-formatted-json-for-calendar-entry/44433946)